# .htaccess redirect with 2 parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, parameters

I am trying to get the following redirect done.

```
website.abc/index.php?page=foo // With one parameter
website.abc/foo

website.abc/index.php?page=foo&article=bar / With a second parameter
website.abc/foo/bar
```

And it has to be redirected backwards as well.

If i type **website.abc/foo/bar** it should internally being redirected to **index.php?page=foo&article=bar**

I can get it to work with one parameter, but as soon as i'm using the second, the URL looks like this and gives me the 404:

```
website.abc/foo&article=bar.
```

I have tried many different ways of making it possible, but nothing worked.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Go like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bpage=([^&]+)\b [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \barticle=([^&]+)\b [NC]
RewriteRule .* /%1/%2/? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bpage=([^&]+)\b [NC]
RewriteRule .* /%1/? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+)/?)?$ index.php?page=$1&article=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: This example is giving me 404 errors on every page and if i'm on the 2nd level the URL looks like this: website.abc/bar//

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f By adding this line above the 3rd QUERY_STRING i got rid of the 404 and i joined the first 2 query strings into one line. Now the URL is being correctly shown but on the 2nd level it gives me the error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS